# How to remove items from arraylist stored in sharedPreference in android?

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I have an app in which contain items in ArrayList which are stored in shared preference and I want to delete particular items from ArrayList in shared preference. How do I do that

code:-

```
 String jsonData = sharedPreference.getAppsArrayListData();
                        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<WhiteListModel>>() {
                        }.getType();
                        whiteListStorage = gson.fromJson(jsonData, type);
```

shared preference class code:-

```
  private SharedPreferences pref;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
// Context
private Context _context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Sharedpref file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "pref";
private static final String NOTIFICATION = "appData";

public MySharedPreference(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

public void saveAppsArrayListData(String scoreString) {
    editor.putString(NOTIFICATION, scoreString);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getAppsArrayListData() {
    return pref.getString(NOTIFICATION, "");
}
```

}

Comment: Just remove that data as per position or string  from arrayList and reset that value in sharedPreference.

Comment: pls refer some code snipshot

Answer (score 2):

To remove a specific saved pref then use

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.remove("tag_to_delete");
editor.commit();
```

If you want to delete particular items from ArrayList in shared preference then
remove the items from the list with `list.remove(position)` and save it again